# for..else for Option types in Scala?

Tags: scala, monads, for-comprehension

Suppose I have two Options and, if both are Some, execute one code path, and if note, execute another.  I'd like to do something like

```
for (x <- xMaybe; y <- yMaybe) {
  // do something
}
else {
  // either x or y were None, handle this
}
```

Outside of `if` statements or pattern matching (which might not scale if I had more than two options), is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: (sorry for commenting a question so old) it's an interesting question, but why not just use a match?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Very close to your syntax proposal by using `yield` to wrap the `for` output in an Option:

```
val result = { 
  for (x <- xMaybe; y <- yMaybe) yield {
    // do something
  }
} getOrElse {
  // either x or y were None, handle this
}
```

The `getOrElse` block is executed only if one or both options are None.

Answer (score 12):

You could pattern match both `Options` at the same time:

```
(xMaybe, yMaybe) match {
  case (Some(x), Some(y)) => "x and y are there"
  case _ => "x and/or y were None"
}
```

Comment: This isn't bad, but I think I like the getOrElse on the for a bit better

Comment: I prefer the clearer intention of this answer, the getOrElse takes more time to understand.

Answer (score 6):

The `traverse` function in Scalaz generalises your problem here. It takes two arguments:

1. `T[F[A]]`
2. `A => F[B]`

and returns `F[T[B]]`. The `T` is any traversable data structure such as `List` and the `F` is any applicative functor such as `Option`. Therefore, to specialise, your desired function has this type:

- `List[Option[A]] => (A => Option[B]) => Option[List[B]]`

So put all your `Option` values in a `List`

- `val z = List(xMaybe, yMaybe)`

Construct the function got however you want to collection the results:

- val f: X => Option[Y] = ...

and call `traverse`

- val r = z traverse f

This programming patterns occurs very often. It has a paper that talks all about it, [The Essence of the Iterator Pattern](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf).

note: I just wanted to fix the URL but the CLEVER edit help tells me I need to change at least 6 characters so I include this useful link too (scala examples):
http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2011/06/essence-of-iterator-pattern.html

Comment: I don't understand. Where does the "or else" comes in here? Also, it seems to depend on `xMaybe` and `yMaybe` being of the same type -- `List` itself will the LUB of them, which doesn't seem to fit what is being asked.

Comment: I have made an error here sorry. I have mixed up traverse and sequence, which are very closely related (can be defined in terms of each other).

Comment: sequence or traverse, I don't see either helping much here.  First, you'd probably use a list, which would mean xMaybe and yMaybe couldn't be different types of Option, right?  Also, wouldn't you have to pattern match to do anything with the parts of your Some result?  If so, the other pattern matching solution would be simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Why would something like this not work?

```
val opts = List[Option[Int]](Some(1), None, Some(2))
if (opts contains None) {
  // Has a None
} else {
  // Launch the missiles
  val values = opts.map(_.get) // We know that there is no None in the list so get will not throw
}
```

Comment: It could work, but then how ate you working with what's inside the List?

Comment: @Bradford: Updated the question - map over them and pull the values out.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the number of values you are dealing with, then Tony's answer is the best.  If you do know the number of values you are dealing with then I would suggest using an applicative functor.

```
((xMaybe |@| yMaybe) { (x, y) => /* do something */ }).getOrElse(/* something else */)
```

Answer (score 2):

You said you want the solution to be *scalable*:

```
val optional = List(Some(4), Some(3), None)

if(optional forall {_.isDefined}) {
    //All defined
} else {
    //At least one not defined
}
```

EDIT: Just saw that *Emil Ivanov*'s solution is a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, we can alternatively use [`Option#zip`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/Option.html#zip[A1%3E:A,B](that:Option[B]):Option[(A1,B)]) which concatenates two options to Some tuple of their values if both options are defined or else None:

```
opt1 zip opt2 match {
  case Some((x, y)) => "x and y are there"
  case None         => "x and/or y were None"
}
```

Or with [`Option#fold`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/Option.html#fold[B](ifEmpty:=%3EB)(f:A=%3EB):B):

```
(opt1 zip opt2).fold("x and/or y were None"){ case (x, y) => "x and y are there" }
```

Answer (score 0):

For scaling to many options, try something along these lines:

```
 def runIfAllSome[A](func:(A)=>Unit, opts:Option[A]*) = {
   if(opts.find((o)=>o==None) == None) for(opt<-opts) func(opt.get)
 }
```

With this, you can do:

```
scala> def fun(i:Int) = println(i)
fun: (i: Int)Unit

scala> runIfAllSome(fun, Some(1), Some(2))
1
2

scala> runIfAllSome(fun, None, Some(1))

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the key point here is to think in term of types as what you want to do. As I understand it you want to iterate over a list of Option pairs and then do something based on a certain condition. So the interesting bit of your question would be , what would the return type look like you would except? I think it would look something like this:  Either[List[Option], List [Option,Option]] . on the error side (left) you would accumulate the option which was paired with a None (and was left alone so to speak) . On the right side you sum the non empty options which represent your successful values. So we would just need a function which does exactly that. Validate each pair and accumulate it according to it's result( success - failure) . I hope this helps , if not please explain in more detail your usecase. Some links to implement what I described : http://applicative-errors-scala.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/0.6/pdf/index.pdf and : http://blog.tmorris.net/automated-validation-with-applicatives-and-semigroups-for-sanjiv/